# Can both Yoga and Bodybuilding be done on same day?

Tags: bodybuilding, yoga

I would like to know is it worth doing both Yoga and Bodybuilding on the same day regularly?

Comment: Hi @Himanshu, what would be your own reasons for thinking that it **can't** be done on the same day? Because that seems exactly the thing an answer should be addressing!

Comment: Hi @Ivo,please see the edit summary I have tried to explain what I think..

Comment: To judge "worth" requires a goal, so this is a difficult question to answer right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, yoga and bodybuilding can be done on the same day. Yoga is a specific form of low-intensity exercise and its benefits are thought to arise from the exercise component as well as stress reduction. Unless your bodybuilding session is so intense that you can barely move, I don't see why you shouldn't do Yoga. Since Yoga exercises are generally of low intensity, it won't have too much of an effect on your muscles or metabolism.

Comment: Might stretching of muscles that have endured (sub)maximal contraction have any negative side-effects or would it simply mean you shouldn't push yourself during yoga?

Comment: Many bodybuilders stretch after their workouts, I've never heard anything about negative effects.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, it is best to partake in static stretching after your workout and seeing that Yoga (generally speaking) is pretty much static stretching there should be no harm.

Harm can come from doing static stretching before your workout, especially for lower-body exercises. It is recommended before workouts to do some dynamic stretching (lunges as opposed to holding a strech like bending over to touch your toes).

There has been some research on the matter. Check out this link: http://chrisfry.hubpages.com/hub/Stretching-Before-Sport

So in short, no, it is not a problem as long as you do your yoga after your bodybuilding workout!

Comment: This is the correct answer provided when the OP says "yoga" they mean stretching and not something like Pilates.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already covered the important ground of whether yoga can be paired with working out, but I'd make some suggestions on the ordering. Many people under-estimate the amount of "work" that can be involved in a number of yoga poses, particularly holds. I've found personally that specific muscles are often too weak for a robust well-rounded session of yoga after lifting weights.

I feel like I get the most out of both when I get my more vigorous yoga session in as a warm-up before lifting. You may also want to keep in mind that despite yoga's reputation it is perfectly possible to hurt yourself while attempting positions your body isn't in the proper shape to execute prop--and being too tired to maintain good form qualifies.

The answer probably depends on what sort of yoga, poses and duration you're practicing.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Yoga will stretch the muscles that have just worked (better do the body building part first) and body building will help build the muscles to hold the postures better in yoga!

Comment: perhaps you can add some context to your answer, it us a bit short now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!! I have done cardio, weight training followed by Yoga in the same session. I must say it feels great to finish off the workout routine by Yoga stretches and I feel much rejuvenated afterwards. I basically do Surya Namaskar to finish the routine and it really helps to stretch the muscles and give some relaxation after strenuous workout.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, take into account the following:

- Some Yoga exercises can be dangerous if your form is bad due to you beeing exhausted (as mentioned earlier)
- Depending on what how much Yoga you do, this can also be pretty exhausting and maybe your form will suffer if you do another workout later that day
- It may take you body some time to get used to so much workout in one day

So give it a try, watch your form closely and don't give up to early if it seems to hard at first.

Answer (score 0):

I am just wondering the same. I am an ex boxer, when I was boxing it was really clear to me that no one can do bodybuilding at the same time because there is no strenght for sparring or training with a punchbag. Nowadays I am doing only doing ashtanga yoga. I want also to start bodybuilding. I have noticed that many yoga studios have once a week a day training with kettlebell. I can exercise my shoulders with a 24 kg kettlebell but it doesn't seem to help so much except in one asana (urdhba dhanurasana) in other words ''bridge asana''. I can say that push ups with handles and training my abs was efficient especially in Surya Namaskaras in other words (sun salutations). I could spent less energy, on the other hand if in the previous day I had trained my muscles really hard I wouldn't do them properly. So you have to find the balance. Unfortunately in internet I don't see similar questions or comments about combining bodybuilding training with yoga. Even if the stereotype of a yogi is a thin person I have noticed in yoga studios that many of these women are slightly overweight. 
I found that disgusting! In sitting yoga exercises fat is a real problem because you can not even breath! The whole yoga technic of an asana is based on breathing!

Comment: I appreciate your knowledge about how yoga studios use kettlebells and how training muscles hurts certain poses.

This would be an improved answer if it trimmed out the sentences that sound like personal sharing but don't contribute to answering the question: the first sentence, your plans to start bodybuilding, how you feel about overweight in yoga.

Answer (score 0):

I do yoga in the morning and strength training in the evening. When I follow this routine for a long time I have noticed that   doing yoga in the morning has helped me a lot to over come
DOMS while doing previous day's heavy lifting. So I feel very comfortable and do 4 workouts for a week,plus almost 4 yoga sessions